# Font Face rendering issue

Tags: css, fonts, type-conversion

Im currently building a website and it seems that the font used in the header isnt rendering correctly on windows machines. I've checked the windows machines have cleartype enabled which they do so im wondering if anybody else has come across this issue or knows what the cause is?

**Windows...**

[image]

**OSX...**

[image]

Comment: Can you specify which browsers are affected, the font, weight, spacing etc used by your CSS?

Comment: Download fonts & go to this link http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

use @font-face

Comment: All I can suggest is using Google Web Fonts to get the proper fonts showing. Use http://www.google.com/webfonts and search for the font.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that particular font has not been properly [hinted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting), and that causes numbers to have uneven sizes with the Windows ClearType (mis)renderer.

You can try to fix the issue with the FreeType’s [ttfautohint](http://www.freetype.org/ttfautohint/) tool.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of reasons why fonts render differently from OS to OS and browser to browser. This [SixRevisions article](http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-web-fonts-issues/) discusses some of the challenges using custom fonts online and towards the end there is a section on font rendering. It's a jungle out there.